# change dictionary to dictionary series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column

```
index data
1    {'data': '123'}
2    {'data': '123'}
3    {"data": "123"}
```

I need to change data column to

```
index data
1    {'data': '123'}
2    {'data': '123'}
3    {'data': '123'}
```

The difference is line with index 3
Thank you for your help

Comment: What is difference?

Comment: quotes. index 3

Comment: Corporate needs you to find the differences between this picture and this picture - They're the same picture

Comment: the issue is some of my rows are series and some of the are not that is why it says AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_tolist'

Comment: Isn't it `df.data.tolist()`? https://datatofish.com/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-list/

Comment: oops, there is typo, `print (df.data.tolist())`

Comment: But to be clear in Python there is no difference between ' and "

Comment: the output is [{'data':'123'}, {'data':'123'}, '{"data":"123"}']

Comment: Could it be that your Data is just a string representation of dict or JSON?

Comment: one of my values is a string. Sorry for being unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list comprehension with `if-else` for convert strings to dictionaries:

```
import ast

df = pd.DataFrame({'data':[{'data': '123'}, {'data': '123'},  '{"data":"123"}']})
    

df['data'] = [ast.literal_eval(x) if isinstance(x, str) else x for x in df.data]
print (df)
              data
0  {'data': '123'}
1  {'data': '123'}
2  {'data': '123'}
```

---

```
import json

df['data'] = [json.loads(x) if isinstance(x, str) else x for x in df.data]
print (df)
              data
0  {'data': '123'}
1  {'data': '123'}
2  {'data': '123'}
```